# Laravel: use primary index as foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, innodb

I have a `hasOne` relation between the model `user` and the model `profilePresi`. This means each user has either 0 or 1 president settings. Thus, the primary index of the `profilePresi` table is identical to the foreign key.

This is how I wanted to add the foreign key:

```
Schema::create('profilePresi', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->integer('idMember');
          $table->primary('idMember');
          $table->string('idCountry',2);
          $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('profilePresi', function($table) {
          $table->foreign('idMember')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

However I get the following error:

[image]

How can I fix it? I am using InnoDB engine so I know that I am allowed to set index key as foreign key.

Comment: have your users migration ahead of profilePresi in sequence??

Comment: Will also help to follow Laravel’s conventions for table and column naming. So all-lowercase and underscores, instead of camelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users.id column is likely an unsigned integer, but your profilePresi.idMember is just an integer. To use as a foreign key, they both need to be either unsigned or not. Check if that's the case, and if so, just make the profilePresi.idMember unsigned as well - that should do it. :)

Comment: Making `profilePresi.idMember ` unsigned did work, thank you. However, the `users.id` column is just an auto increment filed `$table->increments('id');`. Are AI field automatically unsigned in Laravel?

Comment: Yup, increments is basically just a shorthand. :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

`$table->integer('idMember');`

use

`table->unsignedInteger('idMember');`