# Cannot make a primary key and foreing key at the same time with migration Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I was trying to make a foreign key in a primary key at one migration.

This is for Laravel 5.7. I have tried different ways to try to achieve my objective. This is my final code.

```
    Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->primary();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('teachers', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

It makes a normal table with "user_id" as a primary key but it isn't a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: @Joseph Whacheng Check this and let me know whether it was useful

Comment: This works, but I don't want to have an extra "id", I want to the "user_id" to be the primary key of the table!

Comment: I do not know if these two links may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420676/laravel-use-primary-index-as-foreign-key  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504219/laravel-schema-builder-primary-key-as-foreign-key

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTeachersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('teachers')) 
        {
            Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('teacher_name');
                $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            });
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('teachers');
    }
}
```

Now You want to set the `foriegn key` of as **id** of `users` table in `teachers` table

**AM I Clear**

Now 
adding the column to techers table and adding foriegn key constarint

**`METHOD ONE`**

**To Add the Column**

> `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`

**To Add Primary Key**

> `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`

Explaination now `user_id` is field name in teachers table `references('id')` is referencing the id `on('users')` is on user table

**`METHOD TWO`**

**To Add the Column**

> `$table->integer('user_id');`

**To Add Primary Key**

> `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->unsigned()->onDelete('cascade');`

Explaination now `user_id` is field name in teachers table `references('id')` is referencing the id `on('users')` is on user table ,`unsigned()` adding `unsignedinteger` to column

**`If Your issue is not solved kindly comment below`**

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```php
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->primary('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

I don't think `primary()` can be chained onto the column definition the way `unique()` can.